# Исключение при работе с классом File

Tags: c#, uwp

При попытке выполнения метода FillClichesFromFile() в вызываемом методе FillClichesFromFile(string path) при проверке на существование файла (if (File.Exists(path))) выбрасывается исключение. Я догадываюсь, что это из-за многопоточности, но не знаю как решить.

Под отладчиком исключение перехватывается нижеследующим кодом и никакой дополнительной информации нет:

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
        UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        };
#endif
```

Не под отладчиком исключение выбрасывается такое:

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.IO.FileSystem.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: IO_SyncOpOnUIThread. For more information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=623485

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

А код такой:

```
    public async Task<string> OpenClichesFileAsync()
    {
        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");

        StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (file != null)
        {
            // Application now has read/write access to the picked file 
            return file.Path;                
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void FillClichesFromFile(string path)
    {
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            string[] massiveOfString;

            massiveOfString = File.ReadAllLines(path);
            myCliches.Clear();

            foreach (string clicheStr in massiveOfString)
            {
                myCliches.Add(new Cliche(clicheStr, 0));
            }
        }
    }

    public async void FillClichesFromFile()
    {
        clichesFilePath = await OpenClichesFileAsync();
        FillClichesFromFile(clichesFilePath);
    }
```

Comment: Вы предлагаете нам самим угадать, какое именно исключение выбрасывается, и что написано в его поле `Message`?

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow. Вы на правильном пути. И впредь никогда не указывайте, какое сообщение об ошибке Вы получаете, чтобы всем было интереснее угадать.

Comment: И сразу по коду — для чего `clichesFilePath` поле, а не параметр функции? Особенно если у вас многопоточный сценарий.

Comment: @VladD мне кажется пора  по исключениям при работе с файлами делать такой же вопрос, как по NullReferenceException.

Comment: @rdorn: Кстати, да. Подобные вопрос попадаются достаточно часто. У нас даже метка [tag:faq] есть.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Прошу прощения, что затупил с видом исключения. Дополнил вопрос. На выходных еще и далеко от компьютера, поэтому не блещу оперативностью с ответами.

Comment: @skaborik: Окей, это уже лучше, но всё равно не то. Нажмите на Break (вы же запускаетесь под отладчиком, да?), откройте информацию об исключении, и перенесите в вопрос всё, что там есть интересного. Включая stack trace. И ради бога в _текстовом_ виде, из диалога с информацией об исключении вполне можно скопипастить текст.

Comment: дополнил, но ясности не внес. Под отладчиком у меня такое окно не появляется, только когда вместо  debug в параметрах ставлю release

Comment: @skaborik у вас windows universal app?

Comment: @PashaPash да, оно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А что, если переписать это и попробовать вот так?

```
public async Task<string> OpenClichesFileAsync()
{
    FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
    openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
    openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");

    StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    return file;
}

public async Task FillClichesFromFileAsync(StorageFile storageFile)
{
    if (storageFile != null)
    {
        var massiveOfString = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(storageFile);
        myCliches.Clear();

        foreach (string clicheStr in massiveOfString)
        {
            myCliches.Add(new Cliche(clicheStr, 0));
        }
    }
}

public async void FillClichesFromFile()
{
    clichesFile = await OpenClichesFileAsync();
    await FillClichesFromFileAsync(clichesFile);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Судя по всему, в UWP есть встроенная защита от потенциальных "замираний" UI. Когда вы пытаетесь запустить долгую операцию в том потоке, в котором обрабатываются события от пользовательского интерфейса, вы получаете ошибку вида

> Synchronous operations should not be performed on the UI thread. Consider wrapping this method in Task.Run.

Она же IO_SyncOpOnUIThread.

Суть ее в том, что запуск долгой операции в UI потоке "подвесит" интерфейс до ее завершения. Т.е. проблема у вас не из-за многопоточности/асинхронности, а из-за их отсутствия. Вам стоит

- Или использовать асинхронные операции + `async`/`await`
- Или выполнять синхронную операцию в отдельном потоке - через `Task.Run` вокруг вызывающего ее кода, который перебросит синхроный вызов в фоновый поток.